# Proof using the Markov inequality

Tags: probability-theory

I have a doubt in a proof: for a random variable **X**, a>0 and t>0 I have to proof using the Markov inequality that $$ \mathbb{P}(X≥ \frac 1t ln(a)) ≤ \frac 1a M_{X}(t)$$

By definition I know that: $$ \mathbb{P}(X≥ \frac 1t ln(a)) ≤ \frac { E[X] }{ \frac { ln(a) }{ t }  } = \frac { t }{ ln(a) } E[X]$$

but how do you get the moment-generating function $M_{X}(t)$ in this proof? I am also thinking that the problem they gave me is wrong, but I hope it's not. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P\{X \geq \frac 1 t \ln (a)\}=P\{e^{tX} \geq a\}\leq \frac {Ee^{tX}} {a}=\frac {M_X(t)} a$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Markov's inequality applies only to (almost surely) **non-negative** random variables. You know nothing about $X$.

Hint 2: How is the MGF defined?